# how to catch an onScroll event in Ti.UI.ListView?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, hyperloop

Is there a way to catch an `onScroll` event in `ListView` like it is done for `ScrollView`?
It is not exposed in SDK, any solution using module or hyperloop is welcome

Comment: Please add a link to what you refer when speaking about `ScrollView`. You should really show some attempts of yours so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is `scrollstart` and `scrollend` on a listview, check the docs https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView-event-scrollend

Comment: and of course `scrolling` https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView-event-scrolling On Android you'll get a scroll event whenever you change direction, on iOS it will only fire when the finger is released.